# Two similar methods, different behaviors setSchema does not fail in both, but MySQL exception in second case?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a simple exercise of connecting to database. Have two methods where one loads batch of Person objects and another of Order objects. Very structurally similar methods yet the one with orders spits:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (order_id,order_no,person_id) VALUES(13,2003,3)' at line 1
```

The prepared statement for method 2 itself is very simplified - as I tried to figure it out what's wrong. Turned out that adding schema name in front of the "order" in PreparedStatement solves the problem. But I am not satisfied with that. Somewhere schema name is the ps and somewhere as `setSchema` is clearly bad.

The question is why `setSchema` won't work in second method when first has no such exception and executes as expected? I did debugging and database field shows for the connection instance shows "ordermanagement" which is the correct name of my schema.

Finally I've run tests separately so the connection is not reused.

Method 1 (which works, no problem)

```
public int[] personBatchInsert(List<Person> personList) throws SQLException {
        int[] insertStatuses = null;

        try {
            obtainedConnection.setSchema("ordermanagement");
            ps = obtainedConnection
                    .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO person (person_id,last_name,first_name, street,city) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
            obtainedConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
            for (Person person : personList) {

                ps.setLong(1, person.getPersonId());
                ps.setString(2, person.getLastName());
                ps.setString(3, person.getName());
                ps.setString(4, person.getStreet());
                ps.setString(5, person.getCity());
                ps.addBatch();

            }

            insertStatuses = ps.executeBatch();
            obtainedConnection.commit();
```

Method 2 (which throws the exception)

```
public int[] orderBatchInsert(List<Order> orderList) throws SQLException {
    int[] insertStatuses = null;

    try {
        obtainedConnection.setSchema("ordermanagement");
        ps = obtainedConnection
                .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO order (order_id,order_no,person_id) VALUES(13,2003,3)");
        obtainedConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

        ps.execute(); // here exception is triggered
        obtainedConnection.commit();
```

[image]

I hope it is really typo somewhere but I just fail to see it.

Comment: Are you connecting as the admin?  If your connecting using the appropriate connection string you shouldn't need to set the schema

Comment: `ORDER` is a keyword, part of `ORDER BY` and needs to be quoted.

Comment: Let me try that, oh god I have that feeling of solution already!

Comment: Yep, that's the culprit, just out of curiosity putting those `order` quotes would make it database vendor dependant won't it? You can put that as answer or I can delete if people wish, I thought of something more serious. Hurray.

Comment: @Aubergine Yes, quoting with backticks would sadly make it MySQL dependent. The simplest way out is to just not use keywords for table or field names :) Of course, different RDBMS's have different keywords :-/

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson sadly that was given as task instructions, I might suspect that the name is deliberate. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER` is a keyword, part of `ORDER BY` and needs to be quoted;

```
INSERT INTO `order` (order_id,order_no,person_id) VALUES(13,2003,3)
```